# Tabulating the sum of a variable within a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am writing a program where a user inputs the number of floors in a building, and then inputs the number of apartments per each floor, and then finally the amount of rent paid in each apartment. The end goal is to have the total amount of rent paid in each floor by summing the rent amounts the user entered per floor.

This is the code I've written:

```
for i in range(1,floors+1):
    floors=i
    apt=int(input(f"How many apartments are there in floor #{i}?: "))
        
    for j in range(1,apt+1):
        rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))
        total_rent=0
        total_rent+=rent
        while rent<1:
            print("The rent amount must be a positive integer")
            rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))
            total_rent+=rent
    
        for j in range(j-1):
            total_rent+=rent
           
    print(f" The rent is ${total_rent}")
```

However when I execute a test run, the total sum of the rent per one or more of the floor is incorrect. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Any example input data? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Try [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Try to articulate what is going on in each step. Does it look right? Maybe you have too many nested loops, how do you think?

Comment: `total_rent=0` you are clearing this every time when you enter `for j` so the total rent you get is for the last floor

Comment: You are incrementing `total_rent` even when you know the user input is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total_rent=0   #this is above forloop

floors = int(input(f"How many floors are there #{i}?: "))  # you have the option to choose floors

for i in range(1,floors+1):
    floors=i
    apt=int(input(f"How many apartments are there in floor #{i}?: "))
        
    for j in range(1,apt+1):
        rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))  
        
        if rent >= 1:
            total_rent+=rent
            
        while rent<1:
            print("The rent amount must be a positive integer")
            rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))
            if rent >= 1:
                total_rent+=rent
            
           
print(f" The rent is ${total_rent}")
```

Answer (score 0):

first initialize the total_rent before the for loop otherwise you set it to 0 for each loop entrance. The second one is, increase the total_rent whenever it is positive, not always. Also, do the same inside the while loop.
Can you check the below code ?

```
total_rent=0
floors = 4
for i in range(1,floors+1):
    floors=i
    apt=int(input(f"How many apartments are there in floor #{i}?: "))
        
    for j in range(1,apt+1):
        rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))          
            
        while rent<1:
            print("The rent amount must be a positive integer")
            rent=int(input(f"What is the rent for apartment #{i}{j:02d}?: "))
            
        if rent >= 1:
            total_rent+=rent
            
           
    print(f" The rent is ${total_rent}")
```

Comment: To avoid repetition, delete the first `if rent >= 1: total_rent += rent`. Use just the second one and take it out of the while loop.